# Design Java Model to achive Embedded and Reference Collections in Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

In mongodb collection we can define relationship in two ways,
1.Embedded
2.Reference

By taking an example of 1 to many relationship,

An embedded collection of patron and address (1-m) looks like below,

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }
```

And a reference collection of publisher and book (1-m) looks like below,

```
{
   _id: "oreilly",
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA"
}

{
   _id: 123456789,
   title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
   author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
   published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
   pages: 216,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}

{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}
```

Since mongodb will create the collection when application load by looking at the model, how can we design the model (java entities), may be with use of annotations, in a Spring Boot environment for achieve those Embedded and Reference collections?

[Ref.](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)